# How to get overflow visible working on an image with flex on Android with React Native V0.61 and Expo

Tags: android, image, react-native, overflow, visibility

I'm using React Native 0.61 with Expo SDK 37 which should support overflow visible as stated in the docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/image-style-props#overflow). Nevertheless I can't get this to work on Android. I know there were some issues to this topic, but they all seem to be closed and resolved on GitHub (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6802).
So how can I get this to work? Or is there even another way to achieve this picture?

Here is a snap where you can see the different behaviors. It behaves like intended on iOS but it's clipping on Android.

Here you can have a look at the code:
https://snack.expo.io/3C9xHTkUp

Issue in pictures:

[image: IOS]

[image: Android]

Answer (score 0):

I now added a negative margin on the image to fix the issue. But this seems not like the appropriate way to do this. It works, but it doesn't feel right, hence I won't tick it as the answer.

It's a bad fix because its not generic and you have to adapt it for different sizes.

https://snack.expo.io/rKfW0pBQa

Comment: With expo sdk 38, something changed again, so the dirty workaround does not work anymore. Does nobody has a simple solution or better approach to that problem?